# Ngnix gunicorn can't enforce to redirect https

Tags: python, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to enforce http to https in my nginx server but I can't. Here is my configration.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  www.mydomain.com mydomain.com;
    return 301 https://$mydomain.com$request_uri; 
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/mydomain/gunicorn.sock;
   }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
```

by default my site can access http and https but I want to redirect http to https.

Comment: If you are using FastAPI, you can use  the `HTTPSRedirectMiddleware`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71314494/17865804).