# How to change the Redirect URI from HTTP to HTTPS within a FastAPI web app using fastapi_msal?

Tags: python, web-applications, azure-active-directory, fastapi, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to setup Azure AD authentication for a web application using FastAPI. I am using the fastapi_msal python package to do this. The problem I am having is that when I go to the web app, I am able to login, but once i am authenticated, it says the redirect URI that the application is using begins with HTTP. However, Azure requires the redirect uri begin with HTTPS unless running the app locally. Does anyone know how I can change the redirect uri to begin with https instead?

The code for my project pretty much exactly resembles the code from this example project [here](https://github.com/dudil/ms-identity-python-webapp). However, I have found a similar project using Flask instead of FastAPI. And there is a specific portion of the code that addresses this redirect uri problem:

```
# This section is needed for url_for("foo", _external=True) to automatically
# generate http scheme when this sample is running on localhost,
# and to generate https scheme when it is deployed behind reversed proxy.
# See also https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#proxy-setups
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_proto=1, x_host=1)
```

Does anyone know how I can do something like this for a web app using FastAPI instead?

The full source code for the Flask app can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp/blob/master/app.py)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [uvicorn \[fastapi\] python run both HTTP and HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69138537/uvicorn-fastapi-python-run-both-http-and-https)