# Why url_for generates URL with localhost as the hostname instead of the domain name?

Tags: python, jinja2, fastapi, templating, starlette

I have a FastAPI web application using Jinja2 templates, which is working fine on `localhost`, but **not** in production. The problem is that is not generating URLs for JavaScript and other `static` files correctly. I have deployed it on EC2 instance using `gunicorn` and `nginx`.

I have this line of code in my HTML file:

```html
<script src="{{ url_for('static', path='js/login_signup.js') }}"></script>
```

The problem is that it is generating the URL like this:

```html
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/login_signup.js"></script>
```

What I want is to generate something like this:

```html
<script src="http://my_domain.com/static/js/login_signup.js"></script>
```

Comment: Probably because you're not serving on `0.0.0.0`, but you've given us no info. How are you starting your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you are using `gunicorn`, you need to make sure you are binding gunicorn to `0.0.0.0`. For example:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:80
```

Additionally, since you are using Nginx, make sure to configure your "server" config section, as described [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/538#issuecomment-780608541):

```
 server {
        server_name example.com
        location / {
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

           ...
        }


    listen 443 ssl;
```

If the above does not solve the issue for you, see other options below.

### Option 1

You can use realtive paths instead, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71306247/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636404/17865804). Example:

```html
<link href="static/styles.css'" rel="stylesheet">
```

### Option 2

You can create a custom function (i.e., `my_url_for()` in the exmaple below), which will be used to replace the URL's domain name (hostname)—you can omit the port number when replacing the hostname, if you are relying on the default port of HTTP (**80**) or HTTPS (**443**) protocol—and use that function inside your Jinja2 templates instead of the usual `url_for()` function. If you would also like to include query parameters in the URL, rather than just path parameters, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70633588/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71068465/17865804). Example:

**Backend**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from typing import Any
import urllib

app = FastAPI()

def my_url_for(request: Request, name: str, **path_params: Any) -> str:
    url = request.url_for(name, **path_params)
    parsed = list(urllib.parse.urlparse(url))
    #parsed[0] = 'https'  # Change the scheme to 'https' (Optional)
    parsed[1] = 'my_domain.com'  # Change the domain name
    return urllib.parse.urlunparse(parsed)
    

app.mount('/static', StaticFiles(directory='static'), name='static')
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='templates')
templates.env.globals['my_url_for'] = my_url_for
```

**Frontend**

```html
<link href="{{ my_url_for(request, 'static', path='/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Serve on `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`. If you're using `uvicorn` which is the default web server for FastAPI, you need to pass `--host 0.0.0.0` when starting the server. For other servers, look up the equivalent flag.