# Configure FastAPI app hosted on hreoku to use HTTPS

Tags: ssl, heroku, browser, fastapi, gradio

I have a gradio app mounted on a FastAPI app and hosted on Heroku, The app should request audio input permission. Locally that works but this is not the case with production. With some research I found that browsers block this kind of permissions over http (can you confirm?), So I think that I have to configure uvicorn to run https. I found this in the [documentation](https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/)

```
$ uvicorn example:app --port 5000 --ssl-keyfile=./key.pem --ssl-certfile=./cert.pem
```

How can I access the ssl files in heroku. and is this even what I should do? Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: You might [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71314494/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71306247/17865804) helpful as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not Uvicorn's responsibility.

If you are using the default `your-app.herokuapp.com` domain, or if you are using Basic- or Professional-tier dynos, HTTPS should already be available.

If you are using a custom domain with Eco dynos, the easiest solution¹ is to upgrade to [upgrade to Basic](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management#common-runtime) dynos to get access to [automated certificate management](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management) (ACM), which uses [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) under the hood:

> If your app is currently running on eco dynos, Heroku enables ACM automatically when you upgrade your app to use Basic or Professional dynos:
>
> ```
> heroku ps:resize web=basic
> ```

Once HTTPS is *available*, you may want to configure a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. Heroku does not do this for you. Referencing the Flask Security Guide, [Heroku recommends](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls) using [`flask-talisman`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman) for this. Out of the box, `flask-talisman` configures several security-related bast practices, including a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.

---

¹If you don't want to do this, your other option is to provide your own certificate via [Heroku SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl). This is more work, and since you have to provide your own certificate can come with significant financial cost.

Comment: I actually found the issue. It was just a typo in redirect. According to my research you solution seems valid, So Thanks for sharing.